# "live reload" do not see new files that were added to assets folder after "ng serve" was executed

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

i have:

1. angular2 application controlled by `angular-cli`
2. `ng serve` for dev purposes and `ng build` for production
3. some microservice which generates some images and copy them to static folder, in current situation - to `./src/assets` folder

problem:
files, that were added to this folder after `ng serve` was executed are not visible by application throwing me next error:

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/test.png'

while other images that were present before `ng serve` was executed are successfully fetching

steps to reproduce:

1. init mock angular application with command `ng new my-app`
2. go to generated folder with command `cd my-app/`
3. create some test file in assets folder with command `echo "this file is visible because it was in folder before ng serve" >> src/assets/test.txt`
4. launch app with command `ng serve`
5. in another terminal window, check that recently created file is visible by url with command `curl localhost:4200/assets/test.txt`
6. verify that curl returned `this file is visible because it was in folder before ng serve`
7. add one more file **without** reloading `ng serve` with command `echo "don't matter because you'll get an error" >> src/assets/error.txt`
8. try to get that file with command `curl localhost:4200/assets/error.txt`
9. verify that you see error

> Error
>
> ```
> Cannot GET
> /assets/error.txt
> ```

10. try to modify test.txt `echo "file modification is visible by live reload" >> src/assets/test.txt`
11. get updated file without reloading ng serve `curl localhost:4200/assets/test.txt`
12. verify that you see

> this file is visible because it was in folder before ng serve file modification is visible
>   by live reload

13. create component with command `ng g component testcomponent`
14. modify app.component.html with command `echo "(open tag)app-testcomponent(close tag)(open tag)/app-testcomponent(close tag)" > src/app/app.component.html`  (change open tag with < and close tag with >)
15. open localhost:4200 in browser and see `testcomponent works!`

as you see from given steps - live reload do not track only new files in assets. newly added component is normally visible without restarting app

so, what i'm doing wrong? it's not very critical (i still can make production build and work with it) but makes some pain during app testing

is it bug or i can't find proper configuration to tell app to watch for incomers in assets also?

ng --version gives me next output

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.41
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.28
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.51
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.16
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try create some kind of registry file in assets folder. Changes applied to this file will be visible and ng serve will reload project. 
**Algorithm:**

- Before ng serve create file in assets folder (for example "List_of_added_files.txt)
- Start ng serve. When your microservice adds file, run some script to change message into List_of_added_files, example: filename. Angular should see changes and rebuild project.